# Selenium WebDriver - unable to upload file with AutoIT

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I'm unable to upload file with AutoIT v3

try with many ways, but no luck to get it work

method one: (`get Element is not currently visible`)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).click();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Documentation\\Script To Upload File.exe");
```

method two: (`get Element is not currently visible`)

```
driver.findElement(By.name("fileName")).click();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Documentation\\Script To Upload File.exe");
```

method three: (`PASSED: testCaseOne, but no file is uploaded`)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).click();   
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Documentation\\Script To Upload File.exe");
```

For the attach link, when I inspect with the `firepath`, it will refer to xpath `"html/body/input"` with 1 matching node

here my html file

```
<input type="file" name="fileName" style="position: absolute; margin: -5px 0px 0px -175px; padding: 0px; width: 220px; height: 30px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; display: none; z-index: 2147483583; top: 457px; left: 459px;"/>
```

Here's the html code for the document upload section:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <dl>
                            <dd class="attachFile">
                                <div class="attachUpload">
                                    <a id="button2" class=" ">
                                        <img class="attachIco" alt="" src="http://qa.seleniumqa.com/ga/en/clean/images/BLANK.GIF"/>
                                            Attach file
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script To Upload File.au3 code

```
; It will wait for 8 seconds to appear File Upload dialog.
; Used Title property of File upload dialog window.

  WinWait("File Upload","",8)

; Set control focus to File name Input box of File Upload dialog.
; Used Class property of File upload dialog window and Class+Instance property for File name Input box.

  ControlFocus("[CLASS:#32770]","","Edit1")

  Sleep(3000)

; Set the name of file In File name Edit1 field.
; "Test.txt" file Is located In AutoIT folder of E drive. So we have to provide full path like E:\AutoIT\Test.txt.

  ControlSetText("[CLASS:#32770]", "", "Edit1", "D:\Documentation\uploadFile.xls")

  Sleep(3000)

; Click on the Open button of File Upload dialog.

  ControlClick("[CLASS:#32770]", "","Button1");
```

**EDIT**: Share the solution with those needed in future

this code not working (not sure why)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).sendKeys("D:\\Documentation\\uploadFile.xls");
```

but in this way, it work

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("D:\\Documentation\\uploadFile.xls");
```

Comment: What is the problem? You don't know how to check if element is loaded?

Comment: Hi @Ya Wang, the file is not uploaded

Comment: Why don't you use `Robot` instead? See this thread - http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test/12872#12872

Comment: Hi @LittlePanda, I think my problem here are more on unable to click on upload link which trigger the dialog window. I have tested the code at other website, and AutoIT v3 part has no issue.

Comment: Hi again @LittlePanda, I tested with `Robot`, but getting the same result with `AutoIT 3`, no file is uploaded. But i manage to upload file in this  [demo site](http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2014/01/textbox.html) with `Robot` & `AutoIT v3` with exactly same code.

Comment: Since the `input type=file` I think `sendKeys()` should be the ideal method for uploading files.

Comment: Hi @LittlePanda, you are right, it works now. my code are `driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).click();`
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("D:\\Documentation\\uploadFile.xls");`. Pls post your comment as answer so I can mark it as correct answer, thanks.

Comment: If WebDriver sendKeys() method works well without AutoIT, better to use it skipping AutoIT or Robot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the input control is file and therefore, using the below line to upload a file should work.

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("the id"));
e.sendKeys("file path");
```

Comment: thanks for your help, not sure why `driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).sendKeys("D:\\Documentation\\uploadFile.xls");` does not work and `driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).click(); ``driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("D:\\Documentatio‌​n\\uploadFile.xls");` is work. Nvm, as long as it work, its fine for me

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your Html file  **input type = file.** if your input type is something else you will need to try with AutoIt or RobotApi.